# How can I update XZ-utils system-wide after building from source?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I downloaded **XZ Utils** from their [website](http://tukaani.org/xz/), and then I built them using `./configure` and `make`, which creates a bunch of binaries. (I tested them and they work.) Now I'd like to have these new binaries accessible system-wide. Doing `sudo make install`, however, is no good, as running `xz --version` shows me the old version.

I tried coping the newer `xz` binary to `/usr/bin`, but this doesn't seem to help.

How can "update" XZ utils such that typing `xz` in a terminal gives me the new binaries?

(I'm running Ubuntu 14.04)

---

**Edit**
`type -a xz` outputs

```
xz is /home/diego/anaconda3/bin/xz  
xz is /usr/local/bin/xz  
xz is /usr/bin/xz
```

`xz --version` outputs

```
xz (XZ Utils) 5.0.5  
liblzma 5.0.5
```

`/usr/bin/xz` outputs

```
xz (XZ Utils) 5.2.2  
liblzma 5.2.2
```

(I assume this is because I copied the new binary here)

`/usr/local/bin/xz` outputs

```
/usr/local/bin/xz: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5: version `XZ_5.2' not found (required by /usr/local/bin/xz)
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include the output of `type -a xz`, `/usr/bin/xz --version` and `/usr/local/bin/xz --version`.

Comment: So, for some reason you have an old version of `xz` with your anaconda setup.

Comment: I removed the anaconda binary, ran `sudo ldconfig` (since I got some errors about the new library not being found), and now `xz --version` shows the new version, and works. SUCCESS! Thank you.

Comment: @muru, what does `type -a xz` do ?

Comment: @George it lists everything that the shell can run as `xz`: builtins, functions, aliases, external executables in `PATH`, and in the order bash prefers them. Simplest way to determine what bash will run when you type a command.

Comment: Please could you post an answer to your own question explaining how you fixed it to help others in the future?

Answer (score 6):

OP's own solution in the comments:

> I removed the anaconda binary, ran `sudo ldconfig` (since I got some
>   errors about the new library not being found), and now `xz --version`
>   shows the new version, and works. SUCCESS!

Answer (score 3):

Cross-posting my solution from
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49741384/xzcat-version-xz-5-2-not-found/49741451#49741451

I had the following similar error on Ubuntu 16.04 when running buildroot on a project that is working for other developers in my group.

I get the same error if I run `xz --version`.

```
xzcat: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5: version 'XZ_5.2' not found (required by xzcat)
```

I was able to work around this issue by installing xz stable release 5.2.3 (2016-12-30).

Thanks to instructions from here, plus ldconfig: https://blog.csdn.net/xhoufei2010/article/details/51280249

Summary of steps:

Download and extract xz-5.2.3.tar.gz from http://tukaani.org/xz/

```
cd xz-5.2.3
./configure --enable-shared
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

Comment: should that just be `./configure --enable-shared` ?